# Is it possible to do something like "row-reverse" and "column-reverse" simultaneously with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

In an application I'm writing, I'm trying to create a 2D grid system that can be expanded indefinitely in any direction. For those of you familiar with LabVIEW, I'm trying to emulate the ability that users have to scroll indefinitely within the front panel and block diagram of VIs.

Using flexbox, I've managed to make it work alright in the upwards, downwards and leftwards directions, but scrolling rightwards is problematic:

[image]

The grid works by nesting a resizable "container" `div` inside a fixed-size "viewport" `div`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="expandable-grid-viewport" ...>
    <div class="expandable-grid-container" ...>
      <div v-for="tile in tiles" ...>
        <GridSquare .../>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

These are the hardcoded aspects of these elements' styles:

```css
.expandable-grid-viewport {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.expandable-grid-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I make the grid track an x/y position corresponding to where the user has scrolled, and modify the style of the viewport based on it:

```js
get viewportStyle() {
  const [viewportWidth, viewportHeight] = this.viewportDimensions;

  return {
    "flex-direction": this.yIndex < 0 ? "column" : "column-reverse",
    "align-items": this.xIndex < 0 ? "flex-start" : "flex-end",
    width: `${viewportWidth}px`,
    height: `${viewportHeight}px`
  };
}
```

Essentially, I flip the direction the container expands in as I cross from the positive side of an axis to the negative (or vice versa) so that the viewport is always flush with at least one corner of the container, and the container expands outwards from there:

[image]

The issue I'm facing is that flexbox only allows me to reverse rows *or* columns but not both together. As shown in the code above, I switch between `column` and `column-reverse` which lets me handle scrolling in the vertical axis properly, but this results in a problem with horizontal scrolling as shown in the GIF. I can change this to be `row` and `row-reverse`, in which case scrolling in the horizontal direction works fine but not the vertical direction.

Is there a way I can do both together? As well as flexbox I've also tried playing around with CSS grid but I haven't had much success.

Comment: That was my guess - my question is how to work around that. It doesn't need to be based on flexbox. CSS grid seemed promising but it doesn't seem to allow reversing things like flexbox does.

Comment: Are you using flex-wrap? Could you provide a demo (just markup + CSS)? I think it is possible to achieve with `order` property if you're not  using flex-wrap.

Comment: @CyberAP Following Felipe's answer I added code to make it switch from `wrap` to `wrap-reverse` as it crossed from the negative to the positive side of the x-axis (and vice versa), and it seems to work great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's possible.

**Spoiler alert**: if you didn't solved all exercices of this GREAT

➡️ **[Flexbox Froggy - A game for learning CSS](http://flexboxfroggy.com)**

yet, then go learn Flexbox in a very funny and instructive way and then come back (or don't because you'll have found the solution on the way :-) - that's how I remembered it's possible btw).
It's fun, granted!

---

So here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/ZoVBpo?editors=0100) where flex items are displayed on reverse on both directions and below a snippet with spoiler.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5%;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.item {
  width: 16%;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkviolet;
}
```

```html
<h1>flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;</h1>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a rockstar. The solution was just to add `"flex-wrap": this.xIndex < 0 ? "wrap" : "wrap-reverse"` to the object returned by `viewportStyle()`.

Comment: Hm, actually there's still an issue. I didn't notice it earlier because I was running the build on macOS which doesn't show the scrollbars for some reason, but on Windows the horizontal scrollbar sort of rebounds and reverses as you scroll in a particular direction: https://i.imgur.com/kocF2dw.gifv

Comment: I worked around this by just making it scroll to the far right if `xIndex > 0`. Sort of a hack but I don't think it's possible purely through CSS. https://i.imgur.com/cAk0u8T.gifv